# Why does generator function slow down during long iterations

Tags: python, networking, generator

```
def clean_data(response):
    #do sth
    return response

def extract_data(response):
    # do some transforms
    clean_response = clean_data(response)
    yield clean_response

def fetch_paginated_data(first_url_of_paginated_response):
    response = requests.get(first_url_of_paginated_response)
    print(response.status_code)
    response_object = response.json()
    yield from extract_data(response_object)

    if isinstance(response_object, dict) and \
            'meta' in response_object and \
            'next' in response_object['meta'] and \
    response_object['meta']['next'] is not None:    
        yield from fetch_paginated_data(response_object['meta']['next'])

api_endpoint = "www.api.com/?filtered=True"
for data in fetch_paginated_data(api_endpoint):
    insert_data_into_db()
    pass
```

I am using generator functions to collect data from an api endpoint and insert them into a local database. For single page responses, this script works fine. However, for paginated responses (30-50 pages) this slows down as the iterations go on the end. I do see many recursive calls for fetch_paginated_data in the call stack during execution (in debug mode). Is this a stack overflow issue? How would I check that? RAM stays constant throughout runtime.

I use this generator method to alternate between api and database tasks to efficiently use resources on each server. Any suggestions to improve this process would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Your generator looks ok at first glance. How did you measure timings? Please post some specific values and executed code. 50 recursive calls shouldn't make any trouble (you don't use significant stack amount, and default recursion limit is 1000 - far beyond your scale).

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted is correct. The code i was working with in development included the initial GET request parameters to each “next” page call. That was slowing down the API calls significantly, causing the function to slow down.